# INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER error message - but app has unique provider authorities ID

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I currenly have a project system in Android Studio where I have many apps that share the same project structure and code.

Since I was unsuccessful in getting flavours fully working (other SO question), I have opted for the following system.

Whenever I need to change to on of my other apps i:

- Keep *src/main/java* just replacing a single import line in each file.
- Remove all other files in *src/main/*
- Copy/paste a shared *res* directory into *src/main/res*
- Copy/paste project specific *res* directory into *src/main/res*
- Copy/paste project specific *assets* directory into *src/main/assets*
- Copy/paste project specific *Androidmanifest.xml* directory into *src/main/Androidmanifest.xml*

This actually works and only takes two minutes. However, when I am deploying my apps (in debug mode at least) and one of the other is already installed, I get INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER error message.

Now, this can of course be solved by deleting the old app, but I would like to have all my apps installed at the same time.

What i do not quite understand is that each app is compiled with its own manifest file where provider is defined like this:

```
<provider
  android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
  android:authorities="com.example-app-flavour-1.app.fileprovider"
  android:grantUriPermissions="true"
  android:exported="false">
  <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_filepaths" />
</provider>
```

i.e. each app **is** compiled with unique authorities

I have tried to

- build | clean project
- build rebuild project
- file | invalidate caches restart

What am i missing here?

(Naurally I would like to get Android Studio gradle flavours to work some day, but for now I am switching my focus to this since it **so** close working perfectly with minimal trouble each time I need to switch app)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with 'providers', how about packages? does each app have it's own package name ?

Comment: Yes, every app has its own package name etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradle also needs to contain this

```
defaultConfig {
  applicationId "com.example.app"
}
```

I had left it out completely